# Estimate a solution to the parabolic equation according to its initial value

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

The following is my question.

Let $F$ be smooth, and $u$ a bounded smooth solution in $\mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R^n$ to the parabolic equation $$u_t+\partial_xF(u)=\Delta u,\ \ \ \ \ u(0)=u_0$$
Show that if $a\le u_0\le b$, then $a\le u\le b$.

I wanted to derive the dependence pattern between $u$ and $u_0$, but I failed. Can someone help me find the relationship between $u$ and $u_0$ so that we can attain the result that $a\le u\le b$ ?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Are you familiar with the maximum principle? If you expand $\partial_x F(u)$ using the chain rule you should see that the maximum principle for the heat equation can be easily adapted.

Comment: Yeah. I have worked out the problem with your hint. I used the maximum principle for Cauchy problem.

Comment: @mathslearner:  you should post yur own answer!  I for one would like to see it.  Probably worth a few votes . . .